# OSTYPE not detected properly on OS X

Tags: makefile

My `Makefile` has:

```
ifeq ($(OSTYPE), "linux-gnu")
  CHROMEDRIVER_EXE?=$(shell pwd)/vendor/selenium/chromedriver.linux.64
elseifeq ($(OSTYPE), "darwin")
  CHROMEDRIVER_EXE?=$(shell pwd)/vendor/selenium/chromedriver.mac
elseifeq ($(OSTYPE), "cygwin")
    CHROMEDRIVER_EXE?=$(shell pwd)/vendor/selenium/chromedriver.exe
elseifeq ($(OSTYPE), "msys")
  CHROMEDRIVER_EXE?=$(shell pwd)/vendor/selenium/chromedriver.exe
elseifeq ($(OSTYPE), "win32")
  CHROMEDRIVER_EXE?=$(shell pwd)/vendor/selenium/chromedriver.exe
elseifeq ($(OSTYPE), "freebsd")
  CHROMEDRIVER_EXE?=$(shell pwd)/vendor/selenium/chromedriver.linux.64
else
    CHROMEDRIVER_EXE?=$(shell pwd)/vendor/selenium/chromedriver.NOTFOUND
endif
```

For some reason, I get the `NOTFOUND` case. Ideas?

I'm on Mavericks, if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be `else ifeq` and possibly you need Darwin not darwin (depending on how $(OSTYPE) is assigned. e.g.

```
else ifeq ($(OSTYPE), "Darwin")
  CHROMEDRIVER_EXE?=$(shell pwd)/vendor/selenium/chromedriver.mac
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues here; the first and most important is that you have not shown us how the value of `OSTYPE` is obtained, so that makes it hard to know exactly what changes you need to make.

The first issue is that as suspectus says, the correct format is `else ifeq` not `elseifeq`.  Because the first `ifeq` doesn't match and the other statements are not recognized by make, you have basically written this:

```
ifeq ($(OSTYPE), "linux-gnu")
    CHROMEDRIVER_EXE?=$(shell pwd)/vendor/selenium/chromedriver.linux.64
    ...a whole bunch of other stuff make doesn't care about...
else
    CHROMEDRIVER_EXE?=$(shell pwd)/vendor/selenium/chromedriver.NOTFOUND
endif
```

If you ever tried to run this where the value of `OSTYPE` did match the first `ifeq` you'd get lots of syntax errors.

The second *potential* problem is that the format `else <condition>` is available in GNU make 3.81 and higher only so make sure you're not using an older version.

The final possible issue is that make is doing a textual comparison and it doesn't know anything about shell quoting.  You are comparing `$(OSTYPE)` to values like `"linux-gnu"`, and that *includes the quotes*.  So your value of the `OSTYPE` variable better include the double-quotes as well, otherwise these values will never match.

Comment: I'm new to `Makefile`'s. `OSTYPE` doesn't appear to be set anywhere. I assumed it was a `Make` thing?

Comment: Nope.  Make does not set that variable (at least, GNU make doesn't set it).  Where you got the idea that it would be set?  It's not described in the documentation, etc.  If you want it set, you'll have to set it yourself.